# Visa enquiry to go to Cyprus

Tags: visas

I am Nigerian with a Schengen visa that expires in 2021. I plan to run the Limassol marathon in March 2018. Do I need a Cyprus visa?

Comment: Your Schengen visa, is it a multiple entry one? (I assume so but better edit it into the question.)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the expiry date (2021), your Schengen visa is obviously a multiple entry visa.

All citizens, except Turkish and Azerbaijanis, with a valid multiple entry Schengen visa can enter Cyprus for up to 90 days within every 180 days period without any further visa.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that a visa might be required if you are competing as a professional athlete. I don't know about Cyprus, but it can be true in other places.